# Update useContext every second

Tags: javascript, reactjs, createcontext

I have a variable "second", which needs to be updated every second. and it was used by multiple components so i placed it in context.

Only for the first time i see correct value and from the next iteration it is coming as undefined.
any advice please

**Output:**

```
state is  {second: 43, error: null}

state is  {second: undefined, error: null}
```

and i'm using `setInterval` inside `useEffect` to update the variable every second

**Code**

```
import React, { useReducer, useEffect } from "react";

export const SecContext = React.createContext();

const initialState = {
  second: new Date().getSeconds(),
  error: null,
};

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "UPDATE_SECOND":
      return {
        ...state,
        second: action.second,
      };
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
};

export const SecContextProvider = (props) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  const updateSecond = () => {
    let second = new Date().getSeconds();
    console.log("state is ", state);
    dispatch({
      type: "UPDATE_SECOND",
      payload: second,
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const timeoutId = setInterval(() => {
      updateSecond();
    }, 1000);
    return function cleanup() {
      clearInterval(timeoutId);
    };
  }, [updateSecond]);

  return (
    <SecContext.Provider value={[state, dispatch]}>
      {props.children}
    </SecContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default SecContextProvider;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for writing this answer, but I am not able to add a new comment.

A minor issue I saw

```
return {
    ...state,
    second: action.second, // you refer to action.second, which is undefined, you need action.payload here
};
```